# Liferay installation with Eclipse Indigo

Tags: tomcat, liferay, eclipse-indigo

I am beginner worker with **Liferay** bundled with **Tomcat** server.
So I downloaded the latest version of Liferay called:

> liferay-portal-tomcat-7.0-ce-ga1-20160331161017956.zip

but when I extracted the archive I found **Tomcat 8** not **7**

[image]

So I faced a problem when trying to work with Eclipse and Liferay IDE with requires at most **Tomcat server 7** installed not 8.

[image]

And that was the error message:

[image]

I didn't find older version of Liferay because all of them are Enterprise Edition. Any Help?

Comment: Which version of Liferay-IDE are you running? Liferay-IDE for Liferay 7 is not yet out, but I believe that some beta- or milestone-builds are already available.

Comment: Where can I find older versions of Liferay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The liferay zip you downloaded is liferay-portal-tomcat-7.0-ce-ga1-20160331161017956.zip

With the file name -

```
liferay-portal = You downloaded Liferay Portal Server, not sdk, src, dependency etc
xxx-tomcat-xxx = You downloaded tomcat bundle
xx-7.0-xx      = You downloaded Liferay portal versin 7.0
xx-ce-xx       = Community Edition
xx-ga1-xx      = General availability
```

There would be many more GA coming.

"but when I extracted the archive I found Tomcat 8 not 7" -- So you got the liferay version as 7 and whatever tomcat is bundled.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Latest Officially supported is version Eclipse MAR.2.
But works with LUNA and NEON well.
About Indigo i haven't tried try installing liferay plugin from [this link](http://releases.liferay.com/tools/ide/latest/stable/)

Help>Install new software>Add>
Name : liferay
Location : http://releases.liferay.com/tools/ide/latest/stable/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Find an older version of liferay here: 
https://sourceforge.net/p/lportal/news/2016/01/liferay-62-ce-ga6-now-available/

For instructions how to add a new runtime environment to the IDE this link might help:

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-1/setting-up-liferay-ide

Comment: The first link leads me to the another links which leads to the last Liferay version

Comment: works for me - Liferay 6.2 is "the older version" (that you're asking for in your comment on the question) CE is on sourceforge - even back into ancient history.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, till now there is Liferay IDE 3.0 only compatible with Eclipse Luna or Mars. Liferay IDE 3.0 support Liferay 7. It has resolved the problem.